# How I loop through ifstream::get without getting EOF?

Tags: c++, get, ifstream, eof

In this small program, I'm just outputting 4 chars to the file and then retrieving them.As you can see in the output the while loop reads only 4 chars and tellp gets the right position but once outside tellp gets -1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out("E:\\test.txt");
    out << "1234";
    out.close();

    ifstream in("E:\\test.txt");

    int i=0;
    char ch;
    while(in.get(ch)){
        cout << "inside while loop ch="<< ch <<" and its position is " << in.tellg()<< endl;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "outside while loop ch="<< ch <<" and its position is " << in.tellg()<< " and int =" << i <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
inside while loop ch=1 and its position is 1
inside while loop ch=2 and its position is 2
inside while loop ch=3 and its position is 3
inside while loop ch=4 and its position is 4
outside while loop ch=4 and its position is -1 and int =4
```

and if I use :

```
while(in.get(ch) && in.peek() != EOF){
    cout << "inside while loop ch="<< ch <<" and its position is " << in.tellg()<< endl;
    i++;
}
```

the output:

```
inside while loop ch=1 and its position is 1
inside while loop ch=2 and its position is 2
inside while loop ch=3 and its position is 3
outside while loop ch=4 and its position is -1 and int =3
```

but for this usage I only get all chars except the last one. and why I'm still getting -1 here after which I can't "seekg" anymore?!!!!!!

How I loop through ifstream::get and getting all chars without getting EOF?

Comment: you are already getting all the characters. what else do you want??

Comment: If you don't get `EOF`, how you'll know that you reached at end ?
If you hate `EOF`, just read exact no. of characters from file.

Comment: You're changing the break-condition of your while. Are you expecting the behavior to be the same? *Why* ?

Comment: I don't want "-1", I want to seekg the stream again which I can't

Comment: that's not the program I care about, what if reading a file of unknown numbers of chars

Comment: You haven't called `seekg()` in *this* code. What do you mean "again" ? If you want to reset the error fail state why not `clear()` first ?

Comment: @pow, what about the second loop which doesn't reach the EOF?

Comment: @TitoTito because you abruptly terminate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I want to seekg the stream again which I can't"*

You can :

Use:

```
in.clear(); //Clear flags
in.seekg(0); //seek to start
```

outside `while`

Answer (score 2):

After each `get()` the stream position is moved on. Once you reached the end of the file and you try to access the character in that position the stream gets into failure mode, i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set. In failure mode the stream won't do anything until you call `clear()`.

Note that calling `tellg()` is rather expensive. If you want to keep track of the position, it is a lot cheaper to keep a counter up to date.

Comment: how "calling tellg() is rather expensive."? I was planning to keep track of specific chars by tellg()

Comment: i was going to put if condition inside while loop:
if(ch == ','){
somecevtor.pushback(in.tellg);
}

Comment: so is the better to do is to "pushback(i counter)"?

Comment: @TitoTito: Each time you call `tellg()` the stream buffer's `seekpos()` ends up being call. This function is `virtual` making it already fairly expensive to call for each `char` even if the operation itself is cheap. For file stream it may result in messing up the internal buffer for each character.

Comment: @TitoTito: Keeping a `std::streamsize` arounmd and incrementing it each time a `char` is read is a lot cheaper, especially if you read individual `char`s anyway. When reading formatted objects things get a bit garder because you can't necessarily see how many `char`s got consumed (in which case I would use a custom filtering stream buffer which keeps track of the character position).

Answer (score 1):

> why I'm still getting -1 here after which I can't "seekg" anymore?

Because the while condition evaluated to false and the `failbit` is set

If you want to do so and if you have a fixed number of characters, then you should be checking for the exact number of characters rather than checking for the stream validity.

Comment: what the while loop has to do with the file condition?!! I don't understand